# Unable to verify ASCII CHARACTER 29 printing in JAVA

Tags: java, ascii

I'm using JAVA and I'm trying to add the ASCII character 29(Group Separator) to a String(alphanumeric) as part of my algorithm. But I'm unable to verify the output since it doesnt get printed.

If its a non-printable character, is there any other way I can verify that it does get added.

Tried 1)Printing it like any other ASCII character 2)Printing its HEX value(0x1D)

```
System.out.println("Test1====="+Character.toString((char)0x1D));

System.out.println("Test3====="+String.valueOf(Character.toChars(29)));
```

Expected Result:Verify its printed.
Actual Result:Unable to verify.

Comment: You can look into the char array of the string you are building (saving it in a variable first), then you can see if it is saved inside the string or not.

Comment: @karthick: Its not duplicate, I had a look into that question before posting my question,and the purpose of both are different.

Comment: @Progman: Yes thats what I'm trying to see how to verify if its saved inside the String or not

Comment: `System.out.println("Test1=====\u001D");` The question shouldn't be can you get the character into the String but can you get it out through your output stream, which is affected by your Java implementation and terminal and user settings and operating system, ….

Comment: fwiw, title says character 29, question text says 0x1d (=29), code sample says 0x1f (=31).

Comment: @another-dave: Edited the question. Everything else was already correct.Only one line(System.out.println("Test1====="+Character.toString((char)0x1F)); was a typo from me, and thats been modified now.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe write a function that traverses a string and compare every char to 
Character.toChars(29)? Something along the lines of:

```
String str = "Foo Bar" + yourCharacter29ToString;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
if(Character.toChars(29) == str.charAt(i)){
 return true;
    }
  }
return false;
```

This could be enough as a proof of concept. (i did not check above code - read it as pseudo-code please)

Comment: Sure I will try this and updated you in few minutes.

Comment: Thanks @hyperlinq.This helped ,almost. Just changed the Character.toChars(29) to its hex value (0x1D) since only this format was  compatible.Thanks.

Comment: It cannot possibly be the case that toChars(0x1d) works and toChars(29) does not.  It is the exact same number in both cases; numbers are not "hexadecimal" or "decimal" in the machine, these are just two different ways of writing the same thing in the source code.

Comment: @another-dave: Was wondering the same, why it worked with 0x1d and not 29. Below table at *this link* helped to clarify: https://www.systutorials.com/4670/ascii-table-and-ascii-code/                .

Comment: Decimal Octal Hex   Binary   Character   
   -------     -----    ----    --------  ---------------------------- 
       028  034  0x1C  00011100   FS  (File Separator)
       029  035  0x1D  00011101   GS  (Group Separator)
 ctrl  030  036  0x1E  00011110   RS  (Request to Send)(Record Separator)
 code  031  037  0x1F  00011111   US  (Unit Separator)

Comment: It appears unformatted here. Copy paste to a text editor and it comes out fine, formatted

Answer (score 1):

To see which codepoints are in a `String`, you can use `Character.getName(codepoint)`

```
int[] codepoints = ("Test3====="+String.valueOf(Character.toChars(29)))
    .codePoints()
    .toArray(); // optionally, set up for traditional for loop

for (int codepoint : codepoints) {
    char[] utf16 = Character.toChars(codepoint); // always one or two code units

    if (utf16.length == 2) {
        System.out.println(
          String.format("U+%04X \\u%04X\\u%04X %s", 
            codepoint, (int)utf16[0], (int)utf16[1], Character.getName(codepoint)));

    } else {
        System.out.println(
          String.format("U+%04X \\u%04X %s", 
            codepoint, (int)utf16[0], Character.getName(codepoint)));
    }
}
```

The UTF-16 character encoding encodes a codepoint from the Unicode character set with one or two code units (`char`).

(Not sure how the existence of the ASCII character set is relevant to this project—or most any project. If you have bytes for ASCII-encoded text or need bytes for ASCII-encoded text, that's a different question. But, Java uses UTF-16 for text datatypes.)

Comment: Upvoted for the comment that (to paraphrase) not all text is called "ASCII". One might think that after 28 years of Unicode the world would have got it :-)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Tom Blodget !